# What's the best label for an 'occurrences' field?

Tags: input-fields, labels

I have a field where the user needs to enter the number of times they want to send out a document but need a better label.

Firstly, they select the frequency (weekly, monthly, yearly) and then there is this ambiguous occurrences field where they need to type a number to represent the number of times this should be repeated.

[image: Wireframe of current fields]

i.e. Weekly 7 would result in the document being sent weekly for 7 weeks

I've noticed Google has something like this, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

[image: Google's solution]

What is the most appropriate way to approach this?

Comment: You can start by spelling 'occurrences' correctly :)

Comment: Why is the Google solution not right for your application?

Comment: @kenMohnken well I wouldn't need the never since this is a recurring template. The other two options aren't necessarily wrong, I simply wondered what alternatives there are. 
The phrasing will be translated into various European languages and wanted something that was clear and easily translated :)

Answer (score 7):

"Repeat this event until" and then have a date selector.

edit: date.

Comment: you mean "date"?

Comment: @vsz yes, will fix.

Answer (score 5):

MS Outlook could be of use in this situation:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could update the labels to read like the sentence in natural language. Use default values for the secondary field so the user isn't forced to provide input.

```
Frequency
[ weekly    v] for [ 2 ] weeks

[ monthly   v] for [ 2 ] months

Or allow mode selection for termination

[ weekly    v] [ for  v] [ 2 ] weeks

[ weekly    v] [ until v] [ {next week's date} ]
```

using a date type input and/or launching a calendar picker in the "until" case.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set the label relevant to the selection from the first menu.

So if they choose "Weekly" set the label to "Weeks" so when they pick 7 they'll know they're setting "7 weeks". Same for Daily/Days, Yearly/Years.

You could also test putting a # sign or "Number of " in front of it so it will read "# weeks" or "number of weeks", that way it will further reduce potential confusion. Although it may be too verbose so I recommend testing.

Comment: +1. Was going to say pretty much the same thing. "Number of weeks". or "Number of months". "Number of days". What could be more clear?